# How many Azure Service Bus Instances do I need for Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, onpremises-gateway

In our Azure Tenant, we are using Logic Apps.
The Logic Apps get data from an on-premises data source. 
We are using the Microsoft On-Premises Data Gateway to connect to our on-prem data sources. 
Our on prem data sources are :
1. SFTP file server
2. APIs

Do I need or would I need a service bus for each Logic App connector? Or can all connectors use the same Service bus?

Comment: Oh dear. You need the Service Bus to integrate with the On-premises Data GW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have found you answer elsewhere but just making a post for the benefit of others coming across this.

The service bus mentioned in the [architecture of the on-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-onprem-indepth) is a hidden component and is managed when you setup the gateway. What one should consider though is having more than one gateway depending on [load and for high availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-high-availability-clusters) as part of a gateway cluster.